# Can't change from iBus to fcitx

Tags: gnome, 18.04, ibus, fcitx

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME, and I'd like to use use fcitx instead of iBus because I usually type East Asian languages. I installed the `fcitx` package, went into Language Support, and changed "keyboard input method system" to fcitx. However, after I reboot, I still get the iBus input method menu. How can I finally get rid of iBus and switch fully to fcitx?

(Please do not convince me to stay with iBus; Sun Pinyin and `ibus-mozc` are virtually unusable.)

Comment: I can't comment yet...
How did you manage to make it work ? I'm desperately trying to make things work, tried everything I could find on the net, nothing seems to work. [The link to the post where I link all the things I've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111320/chinese-input-ubuntu-18-04-nothing-works) Thanks you in any case

Answer (score 3):

I have also encountered such a problem. The root cause is that Ubuntu switch to GNOME since 17.10 and GNOME may not support fcitx well at present. The following scripts may be helpful to you:

**Step 1** check fcitx be installed

```
sudo apt install fcitx fcitx-mozc
```

**Step 2** open ~/.pam_environment with your text editor and set the following environment variables to start fcitx

```
XMODIFIERS DEFAULT=@im=fcitx
GTK_IM_MODULE DEFAULT=fcitx
QT_IM_MODULE DEFAULT=fcitx
```

**Step 3** add an autostart entry to start fcitx. Search "Startup applications Preferences" in Ubuntu Activities and add an entry for fcitx

```
Name: Fcitx
Command: /usr/bin/fcitx-autostart
Comment: type your favorite description for fcitx
```

**Step 4** reboot and check if fcitx wake up

See more details in this document: https://www.csslayer.info/wordpress/fcitx-dev/how-to-use-fcitx-on-ubuntu-17-10/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04 with GNOME 3.32.1,

1. In `gnome-language-selector` change `Keyboard input method system` to `fcitx`:
2. In `Settings->Region&Language->Input Sources` remove anything like `Chinese(Intelligent Pinyin)`, only keep `English(US)`